# Python - save SSH command output to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, paramiko

I am trying to save the output of a SSH command run using Paramiko module in a CSV file. But the output is saved in wrong format. e.g. every letter in a separate column and everything is shown in 1 row.

Part of Python code which gets the command and writes it to CSV.

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("lastlog")

temp = ""

for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line.strip()
        temp = temp + line


# Open a file and write the output to it
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(temp)
```

Output of `print line.strip()` is in the following format:
[Command Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avEMZ.png)

Can someone tell me please what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best I got. There might be a better way to do this, but at least this solves the purpose.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("lastlog | awk \'{if (NF==4)print$1\",,,\"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4; if (NF==8) print  $1\",\"$2\",,\"$3\" \"$4\" \"$5\"\"$6\" \"$7\" \"$8;if (NF==9) print $1\",\"$2\",\"$3\",\"$4\" \"$5""$6\" \"$7\" \"$8\" \"$9}\'")
log_output = stdout.readlines()
log_output_clean = [i.strip("\n").split(",") for i in log_output[1:]] # First row did not parse well,so ignored it
log_output_clean.insert(0, ['Username', 'Port', 'From', 'Latest']) # Adding header row
with open('log_output.csv', 'w') as output_fn:
    wr = csv.writer(output_fn)
    wr.writerows(log_output_clean)
```

Comment: thank you for your input. Your code gives the following error:     stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("lastlog | awk \'{if (NF==4)
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. I tried to use """ instead of a single ". But that only printed the Headers in the csv.

Comment: I removed the spaces and edited the answer. The pipe command is just one line. I guess that is why there is that syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Your code definitely looses new lines.

This should do:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("lastlog")

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(stdout, f)
```

---

I'm not sure about the *"every letter in a separate column"*.

Comment: Thank you for providing the change. However, now it saves all the data in 1 column (column A). How can I change it so that it saves the headers in different columns? e.g. Username should be in column A, Port in B etc.